# What does it mean for a predicate in Prolog to be "shallow" or "deep"?

Tags: list, prolog, predicate

For example, I am tasked with creating two predicates that will remove every other element from a list. However, one is meant to be 'shallow', and the other 'deep'. Any help on what these terms may be referring to?

Comment: Do you have the original text?

Comment: Can (some of) the elements of the input list be lists themselves?

Comment: It's perhaps refering to shallow (e.g. [1,2,3,4]) or deep (e.g. [1,[2,3],[4,[5,6]]]) lists rather than predicates?